# Как сократить конструкцию old в laravel

Tags: php, laravel, requests

уважаемые участники форума и мега программисты))
Учусь, учусь и еще раз учусь))

Необходимо помочь сократить конструкцию old() в laravel и чтобы была с одним foreach, думаю это возможно, но пока мое серое вещество не так умно как у вас!

```
                           <select name="city_id">
                                <option value="">-</option>
                                @if(old('city_id'))
                                    @foreach($city as $city_one)
                                        <option value="{{ $city_one->id }}" {{$city_one->id == old('city_id') ? 'selected' : ''}} >{{$city_one->name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                @else
                                    @foreach($city as $city_one)
                                        <option value="{{ $city_one->id }}"{{ $city_one->id == $shop_map_point_one->city_id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$city_one->name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endif
                            </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <select name="city_id">
      <option value="">-</option>
        @foreach($city as $city_one)
          <option value="{{ $city_one->id }}" {{$city_one->id == old('city_id', $shop_map_point_one->city_id) ? 'selected' : ''}} >{{$city_one->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```